# android ndk and cygwin

Tags: c++, c, android-ndk, cygwin

I am trying to install android ndk using cgywin. I've download the android  ndk and unzip it. I've also installed cygwin.

I would like to mention that I am a windows user.

I don;t know how to install androidn ndk. In cygwin here is the error when I run ./build-ndk

```
Android NDK: Could not find application project directory !
Android NDK: Please define the NDK_PROJECT_PATH variable to point to it.
/cygdrive/c/android-ndk/build/core/build-local.mk:130: *** Android NDK: Aborting                                                        .  Stop.
```

What am I missing? Need some help please.

EDIT:

I SOLVED THE PROBLEM BY RECOMPILING THE CYGWIN WITH MAKE AND GCC. SECONDLY I BULD THE PROJECT WIRH ANDROID=NDK

Answer (score 1):

To use Android NDK properly you will need cygwin (additionaly to SDK requirements): http://www.cygwin.com/ Cygwin out-of-box is compatible with the recent Android NDK (r8 at the time of writing this answer).

Also, alternative NDKs exist, i.e. Crystax NDK (http://www.crystax.net/en/android/ndk) which is based on gcc 4.6 instead of 4.4.